# PiCamera and continuous_capture with python and raspberry pi

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using a raspberry pi and trying to create a video stream using flask and the pi camera library. My understanding is that I need to use continuous_capture to get the lowest latency within the system.

However, I can't find a way to preview these images that are supposedly being taken. Is there a way I can view these before I try and implement it into flask which has many issues itself as I will be using the falsk website to control a robot as well.

Any suggestions on how to do this are appreciated as well as telling me there is an easier way to do it. Please note I am only an intermediate programmer so nothing too complex for me to understand as this is the whole idea of the project.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for `capture_continuous`.

Here's the general process:

- Import the necessary packages
- Pause to allow the camera to warm up
- Iterate through the camera frames

  - Capture and show the frame

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2

# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

# allow the camera to warmup
time.sleep(0.1)

# capture frames from the camera
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    image = frame.array

    # show the frame
    cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # clear the stream in preparation for the next frame
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
```

Comment: this is very helpful. Thanks, however, I always struggle to install cv2. Is there an easy way that you do it?

Comment: Depends on the model that you are using.  Good docs: [PI 2](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/23/install-opencv-and-python-on-your-raspberry-pi-2-and-b/) and [PI 3](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/).  Unfortunately, it is quite cumbersome.

Comment: I have Pi 3 with python 3 and no matter how hard i try i cant get any version of CV installed. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: The process is delineated well in the hyperlinks from my last comment. To my knowledge, this is the only way to install.

Comment: @BeardedDork thanks for the answer. It works, but I get a very low FPS. Is there any way to make it faster ?